# Deploy an ARM template on DevTestLab failure - missing snapshot error

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-devtest-labs

Prerequisites:

- DevTest Lab with Azure Repos connected (as a source for ARM Templates)
- working ARM template
- Custom images in that DTLab

You try to deploy an ARM template and all deployments fail with error:
[image]

Please note, that the mentioned in error message snapshot ("mshasstupiderrors") is not mentioned in ARM template (in my case, I've used only standard Windows Server 2019).

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to check if there is a custom image in that DTLab with the name "mshasstupiderrors" which is missing a connected snapshot.

This post is triggered by 7 months of support case battle with MS - they agreed that this an issue (ARM template deployment validation?), but were not able to find a reason asked to close the ticket...